# System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder vs Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5, antixsslibrary

In ASP.NET 4.5 there is a new namespace `System.Web.Security.AntiXss` which includes encoding routines from version 4.0 of the AntiXssLibrary (http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/whats-new#_Toc318097382).

The latest version of AntiXssLibrary is 4.2.1.

I'm quite confused what type I should use for encoding output HTML in my new project: built in `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder` or `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder` from AntiXssLibrary. Could anyone tell me what type is preferred to use and why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The one in the System.Web.* namespace is a clone of the one in the Microsoft.Security.* namespace, but the System.Web one is slightly tweaked for better performance characteristics.  We recommend the System.Web one going forward.

If you set the `<httpRuntime encoderType>` setting as described at http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/whats-new#_Toc318097382, then you can just use the built-in encoding routines like HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, and the implementation will be provided by the Anti-XSS libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that I should always use this System.Web class regardless of new versions of the `AntiXSS library`?

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov there is no real difference between the two. They're both updated together. Use whichever one is more convenient. The System.Web one is serviceable (since it's part of the .NET Framework), so we're pushing people toward it if they're able to use it.

Comment: @Levi, Who told you that System.Web is the one going forward? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, I was speaking on behalf of the ASP.NET team when I made that statement.

Comment: That link is dead now

Comment: Updated link on preventing cross-site scripting: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cross-site-scripting.html

Comment: The System.Web.* version doesn't seem to include the Ldap related methods, whereas the Microsoft.Security.* version does.